# Google Charts and real time updates

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm thinking of using the google charts api, in particular column charts and scatter plots. I want to know that can these charts be updated constantly by data it receives from the server via a websocket.

My understanding is that this data will first be added to a data table and then plotted onto a chart. So if data is being updated in the table will this update the chart in 'real time'.

Another question is I'll also have an instance when the columns cannot be defined straight away but again will be updated by the received data; again can google charts handle this.

Thanks

Comment: If you populate your Google Chart from JavaScript, you can also modify or repopulate the chart from JavaScript. Worst case you might have to redraw the entire chart. Which is not as bad performance-wise as you might think: the entire thing is drawn client-side anyway.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when I try updating once a second a chart - it almost freezes my Chrome...  this brings up a question - is google charts really meant for real time data display? it does seem to work brilliantly with conveniently displaying static data. Did you eventually find a solution for real-time charts?

Comment: Just modify the DataTable and call draw, seems to perform OK. Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/0w1nbyxw/1/.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know about google charts, but recently I discovered [Smoothie Charts](http://smoothiecharts.org/). It can do real-time(smooth). The only problem is that I does only work in Chrome, Firefox according to this [Introducing Smoothie Charts](http://joewalnes.com/2010/08/10/introducing-smoothie-charts/) post.

Or maybe [highCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). A real-time example at [jsfiddle](http://tinyurl.com/d53b3o2).

Comment: that jsfiddle goes a bit wild if you speed it up :( http://jsfiddle.net/2JvF9/475/

Answer (score 1):

if you have

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

you can do

```
data.addRows([2015,10])
chart.draw(data);
```

and it updates the chart

I made a button that adds data in this JSfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kdn2ojxb/3/